# Multiple Markers in APEX Map Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, oracle-apex

I want to develop a map chart but I need multiple markers on each state.

I would like to display sales by state and income by state, so I want to display two markers and two values on each state.

I searched a lot in google, but it was showing multiple markers in google maps, only but my requirements are different.

If anyone can help with that, it will very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my apex-plugin on apex-plugin.com. this places multiple markers on a google map.:

[www.apex-plugin.com](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/multimarker-map_403.html)

to see how it works check my demo page right here:

[MultiMarker Demo](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=84616:99901)

Maybe this helps?

Comment: Hi PT_STAR, Thanks for reply. In google maps it will getting multiple markers but i need multiple markers in normal map charts only. How can i achieve that.

Comment: what do you mean with "normal map charts"? Oracle spatial maps?? See the following link (in German language)  http://www.doag.org/home/aktuelle-news/article/geodaten-fuer-alle-oracle-locator-spatial-und-maps.html  maybe you can ask the author (Carsten Czarski). He is very familar with APEX and maps.